# Как зарегистрировать класс приложения в файле манифеста?

Tags: java, android

Как зарегистрировать мой класс  в манифесте Android? Я просмотрел множество руководств в Интернете и до сих пор не могу понять . Мой класс приложения называется men.java. На первом скриншоте на манифесте указаль men.java как LAUNCHER. А на вотором скрине MainActivity но уже без men.java. Как мне зарегистрировать его в коде файла манифеста ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Манифест

men.class(java)

```
public class men extends AppCompatActivity {
    ViewPager2 viewPager2;
    ArrayList<ViewPagerItem> viewPagerItemArrayList;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.men);
        viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        int[] images = {R.drawable.a,R.drawable.b,R.drawable.c,R.drawable.d,R.drawable.e};
        String[] heading = {"Baked","Grilled","Dessert","Italian","Shakes"};
        String[] desc = {getString(R.string.a_desc),
                getString(R.string.b_desc),
                getString(R.string.c_desc),
                getString(R.string.d_desc)
                ,getString(R.string.e_desc)};
        viewPagerItemArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i =0; i< images.length ; i++){
            ViewPagerItem viewPagerItem = new ViewPagerItem(images[i],heading[i],desc[i]);
            viewPagerItemArrayList.add(viewPagerItem);
        }
        VPAdapter vpAdapter = new VPAdapter(viewPagerItemArrayList);
        viewPager2.setAdapter(vpAdapter);
        viewPager2.setClipToPadding(false);
        viewPager2.setClipChildren(false);
        viewPager2.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
        viewPager2.getChildAt(0).setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);

    }
}
```

Fragment1.java

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment3,container,false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

> UPDATE FRAGMENT1.JAVA

```
public class fragment1 extends Fragment{
    ViewPager2 viewPager2;
    ArrayList<ViewPagerItem> viewPagerItemArrayList;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment1);
        viewPager2 = viewPager2.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
        int[] images = {R.drawable.a,R.drawable.b,R.drawable.c,R.drawable.d,R.drawable.e};
        String[] heading = {"Baked","Grilled","Dessert","Italian","Shakes"};
        String[] desc = {getString(R.string.a_desc),
                getString(R.string.b_desc),
                getString(R.string.c_desc),
                getString(R.string.d_desc)
                ,getString(R.string.e_desc)};
        viewPagerItemArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i =0; i< images.length ; i++){
            ViewPagerItem viewPagerItem = new ViewPagerItem(images[i],heading[i],desc[i]);
            viewPagerItemArrayList.add(viewPagerItem);
        }
        VPAdapter vpAdapter = new VPAdapter(viewPagerItemArrayList);
        viewPager2.setAdapter(vpAdapter);
        viewPager2.setClipToPadding(false);
        viewPager2.setClipChildren(false);
        viewPager2.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
        viewPager2.getChildAt(0).setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);

        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment1,container,false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

> ERROR: Cannot resolve method 'setContentView' in 'fragment1'

Comment: Если вы хотите отображать ваш ViewPager на вкладке "Главная", то вам надо этот pager перенести в Fragment1, класс men вам не нужен. ЗЫ Старайтесь пользоваться стандартами при именовании классов и переменных (в частности классы именуются CamelCase'ом).

Comment: Не class, а activity. Недавно был такой вопрос, поищите ответ

Comment: @YuraIvanov как можно перенести? помогите новичку пж)

Comment: В разметку `R,layout.fragment3` перенесите то, что у вас R.layout.men. А весь код, который у вас в классе men в onCreate перенесите в onViewCreated в фрагменте. только findViewById станет view.findViewById. Это если кратко, и возможно не понятно. Вам просто надо разобраться, что у вас уже есть MainActivity и ее достаточно. Все остальное располагайте в фрагментах. Лучший вариант взять книжку какую-нить, там точно про фрагменты и активити рассказано. на startandroid'е еще можно уроки почитать.

Comment: @YuraIvanov посмотрите пожалуйста на последний код "FRAGMENT1.JAVA"  написал как понял) там ошибка на setContentView погуглил не получилос :(  | и отдельное спасибо за советы про уроках

Comment: onCreateView остается такой же как был. все остальное в onViewCreated, setContentView не нужен. viewPager2  = view.findByView(...). (view - это параметр onCreateView)

Answer (score 0):

Исправьте манифест

```
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".men"
        android:exported="true" >
    </activity>
```